# как запретить клик больше одного раза на каждый input

Tags: javascript, события

Есть 3 inputa. При нажатии на каждый должно отобразитьcя в консоль значение value.
Но надо сделать чтобы сработало на каждом inpute только по одному разу.

```
<div id="task2">
<input type="text" value="text1111"> <br>
<input type="text" value="text2222"> <br>
<input type="text" value="text3333"></div>

let task2 = document.getElementById('task2')
task2.addEventListener('click', something);
function something(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    console.log(target.value);
}
```

Comment: Вам необходимо полностью отключить инпуты после клика или оставить их рабочими, но больше не выводить в консоль value?

Comment: второе. оставить инпуты рабочими. но чтобы в консоль value вывелись только по одному разу.

Comment: если просто removeEventListener то вывод в консоль сработает вообще только один раз. а надо чтобы по одному разу для каждого инпута

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
document.querySelectorAll('#task2 input').forEach(
  i => i.addEventListener('click', something, {once: true})
);
```

Comment: это аналогично removeEventListener. тогда вывод в консоль сработает вообще только один раз. а надо чтобы по одному разу для каждого инпута

Comment: @сашаиванов: вывод в консоль сработает для КАЖДОГО инпута только ОДИН РАЗ. Всё верно же?..

Comment: @UModeL Это я добавил выборку и цикл после комментария.

Comment: @Igor: ситуацию не меняет - лучшим ответ не выбран :)

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

При нажатии на инпут удаляем обработчик для этого инпута:

```html
<div id="task2">
    <input type="text" value="text1111"> <br>
    <input type="text" value="text2222"> <br>
    <input type="text" value="text3333">
</div>
```

```js
let task2 = document.querySelectorAll('#task2 input');
task2.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', something));

function something(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    console.log(target.value);
    this.removeEventListener('click', something);
}
```

**EDIT**

Вариант от Igor более предпочтителен в использовании, т.к. структура кода проще и не нуждается в пояснении

Comment: спасибо! у вас тоже все верно, по сути аналогично варианту от Igor.